# Extending ModelState to output my own message - how do I get model state value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, modelstate

I wrote my own extension for ModelStateDictionary, but I am running in to the problem of displaying the inputted value.

Here is my attempt:

```
public static string ToLoggingFormat(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("Input validation error occurred:");

    foreach (var ms in modelState.Values)
    {
        foreach (ModelError error in ms.Errors)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(error.ErrorMessage);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ms.AttemptedValue)) { 
            sb.AppendLine($"Attempted Value: {ms.AttemptedValue}");
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

My problem is that ms.AttemptedValue is always null.  Any ideas please? I have tried ms.RawValue also but that is also null.  The value I am passing in is invalid because it is over the limit and therefore not null.

---

I am adding a custom XML Input formatter as suggested!

```
public class ModelStateXmlInputFormatter : XmlSerializerInputFormatter
{
    public ModelStateXmlInputFormatter(MvcOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var result = await base.ReadRequestBodyAsync(context);
        foreach (var property in context.ModelType.GetProperties())
        {
            var propValue = property.GetValue(result.Model, null);
            var propAttemptValue = property.GetValue(result.Model, null)?.ToString();
            context.ModelState.SetModelValue(property.Name, propValue, propAttemptValue);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I add it like so,

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    // Remove JSON input
    options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType(typeof(JsonOutputFormatter));
    options.InputFormatters.RemoveType(typeof(JsonInputFormatter));
    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;

    // Add our customer XmlInputFormatter
        options.InputFormatters.Add(new ModelStateXmlInputFormatter(options));
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());

})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

But the extension still returns null for ms.AttemptedValue.  Any ideas? :))

This is how I am using the extension:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("myrequest")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyRequest([FromBody] MyRequestType request)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
          Logger.LogThis(ModelState.ToLoggingFormat());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't your values appear in the model errors?

Comment: ErrorMessage is a set message and not the input value. e.g. "The Last name field is over the maximum number of characters permitted."  I am trying to produce "The value 'Smithhhhhhhh' is too long" as an example.

Comment: Not possible unless you remove the MaxLength data annotation from your model, and do you validation manually in your code (e.g. if model.MyLongProperty.Length > 100) { return "The value " + model.MyLongProperty + " is too long";     }  You get the idea

Comment: That's so crazy.  What's the point of AttemptedValue attribute then?! >:(

Comment: That would be a question for the geniuses over at Microsoft

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe `AttemptedValue` is for conversions. Everything from the request body is a string, and the modelbinder must actually convert those strings to their destination types, an int for example. There is no `AttemptedValue` if the destination type is a string, because nothing is "attempted", it just is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this issue, it happens for `JsonInputFormatter`. In Asp.Net Core, there are two ways to bind requst to model, `FromForm` with model binding and `FromBody` with `JsonInputFormatter`. For model binding, it calls `context.ModelState.SetModelValue` to set value for `RawValue` and `AttemptedValue`. But, `JsonInputFormatter` does not implement this feature.

You need to implement this feature in by custom `JsonInputFormatter` like

1. `ModelStateJsonInputFormatter`

   ```
   public class ModelStateJsonInputFormatter : JsonInputFormatter
   {
       public ModelStateJsonInputFormatter(ILogger<ModelStateJsonInputFormatter> logger, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, ArrayPool<char> charPool, ObjectPoolProvider objectPoolProvider, MvcOptions options, MvcJsonOptions jsonOptions) : base(logger, serializerSettings, charPool, objectPoolProvider, options, jsonOptions)
       {
       }
       public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
       {
           var result = await base.ReadRequestBodyAsync(context);
           foreach (var property in context.ModelType.GetProperties())
           {
               var propValue = property.GetValue(result.Model, null);
               var propAttemptValue = property.GetValue(result.Model, null)?.ToString();
               context.ModelState.SetModelValue(property.Name, propValue, propAttemptValue);
           }
           return result;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register `ModelStateJsonInputFormatter`

   ```
   services.AddMvc(opt => {
       var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
       var modelStateJsonInputFormatter = new ModelStateJsonInputFormatter(
                   serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<ModelStateJsonInputFormatter>(),
                   serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>>().Value.SerializerSettings,
                   serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ArrayPool<char>>(),
                   serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ObjectPoolProvider>(),
                   opt,
                   serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>>().Value
           );
       opt.InputFormatters.Insert(0, modelStateJsonInputFormatter);
   }).SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
   ```

Comment: Hi! Thanks, this looks very promising but I did it for XML instead and could not get it working with my extension.  Please see my edit! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var ms in modelState.Keys)
    {
        var value = modelState[ms];
        foreach (ModelError error in value.Errors)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(error.ErrorMessage);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Value.AttemptedValue)) { 
            sb.AppendLine($"Attempted Value: {value.Value.AttemptedValue}");
        }
    }
```

Not tested...

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same as what OP wrote?

Comment: This doesn't work as ModelState does not contain value.Value, only value.AttemptedValue which also yields null. :( Thanks for the attempt though.